# How to use env variable as reference of other env variable?

Tags: laravel, phpdotenv

I am using Laravel 5.4 and `vlucas/phpdotenv` library.

I wants to take reference of one env variable to other env variable e.g.

```
APP_NAME: JUSTDOIT
SIGNUP_KEY: JUSTDOIT_SIGNUP
```

here in SIGNUP_KEY I wants to use whatever APP_NAME it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ahh, I found the answer here, Not removing the question as  it may help to other,

**It's possible to nest an environment variable within another, useful to cut down on repetition.**

This is done by wrapping an existing environment variable in `${…}` e.g.

```
APP_NAME: JUSTDOIT
SIGNUP_KEY: ${APP_NAME}_SIGNUP
```

additionally if you wants to use space in variable value then encluse this with "quotes" e.g.

> SIGNUP_KEY: "${APP_NAME} SIGNUP"

Reference: 
https://github.com/vlucas/phpdotenv#nesting-variables